# Intesection problem with Möller-Trumbore algorithm on 1 dimension of the triangle

Tags: c, raytracing

I am currently working on a raytracer project and I just found out a issue with the triangle intersections.

Sometimes, and I don't understand when and why, some of the pixels of the triangle don't appear on the screen. Instead I can see the object right behind it. It only occurs on one dimension of the triangle and it depends on the camera and the triangle postions (e.g. picture below).

[Triangle with pixels missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sky7z.png)

I am using Möller-Trumbore algorithm to compute every intersection. Here's my implementation :

```
t_solve s;
t_vec   v1;
t_vec   v2;
t_vec   tvec;
t_vec   pvec;

v1 = vec_sub(triangle->point2, triangle->point1);
v2 = vec_sub(triangle->point3, triangle->point1);
pvec = vec_cross(dir, v2);
s.delta = vec_dot(v1, pvec);
if (fabs(s.delta) < 0.00001)
    return ;
s.c = 1.0 / s.delta;
tvec = vec_sub(ori, triangle->point1);
s.a = vec_dot(tvec, pvec) * s.c;
if (s.a < 0 || s.a > 1)
    return ;
tvec = vec_cross(tvec, v1);
s.b = vec_dot(dir, tvec) * s.c;
if (s.b < 0 || s.a + s.b > 1)
    return ;
s.t1 = vec_dot(v2, tvec) * s.c;
if (s.t1 < 0)
    return ;
if (s.t1 < rt->t)
{
    rt->t = s.t1;
    rt->last_obj = triangle;
    rt->flag = 0;
}
```

The only clue at the moment is that by using a different method of calculating my ray (called dir in the code), the result is that I have less pixels missing.
Moreover, when I turn the camera and look behind, I see that the bug occurs on the opposite side of the triangle. All of this make me think that the issue is mainly linked with the ray..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Watertight Ray/Triangle Intersection](http://jcgt.org/published/0002/01/05/). I would much appropriate if you could provide a minimal example where a ray should hit the triangle, but misses it. I had this a long time ago with the Cornel Box - inside the box there were some "black" pixels because on edges none of the triangles has been hit. It's a common problem stemming from floating-point imprecision.

Comment: Thaks for your answer. I tried to change my float variable into double, but it does not make anny difference. I wll try to implement Watertight Ray/Triangle Intersection.
Why do you mean by minimal example where a ray should hit the triangle ? The picture is an example :)